# restore database with permissions for specific login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have a service account (SQL Server login) that needs to be able to restore a database and then execute a specific procedure within this newly restored database. **Can this be done without the sysadmin (or securityadmin) role for the login account?**

Some approaches I tried already:

- Create user for the login within the DB backup before restore - doesn't work, user is 'orphaned' after restore, and sysadmin is required to un-orphan him.
- Giving appropriate server-level privilege to the service account - I failed to find a role that would allow executing procedure within database (other than sysadmin)

Am I missing anything, or is this simply not possible? Workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Server level roles and Database roles are very different. Having a server level role does not implicitly grant you access to a database. The only exception to that is someone with the `sysadmin` role, however, then they are mapped to the `dbo` user when connected to the database.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I understand that you consider it impossible (so far my conclusion as well).

Comment: Why was this question closed? What can I do to reopen? I think the question is clear, I stated what I tried. I omitted code samples because it has to do with restoring database, which is not something you can do with a couple of lines of code.

Comment: I can't see the specific close vote reasons, but I suspect 1 or 2 were for migration to [dba.se] and another not, meaning the question was not migrated. Ordinarily I would vote to reopen, but I do think it is better off on [dba.se].

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd suggest you set up a service that does all the work and has all the necessary permissions and then let this person simply call that service. That's the way to be the most protected on your server.

However, if you want to, you can give them access to the [securityadmin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15). That will allow them to add users to the database after they restore it. It's less than the full sysadmin role, but not by much.

Comment: What kind of service do you have in mind? Can you expand a bit, or give an example please?

Comment: You could do something as simple as set up a SQL Agent job and give them permission to run it. That job runs as SA, does all the necessary work to restore and set up your database, all without exposing your system to people who probably shouldn't have that much access. However, you could do it with PowerShell, Python, pick your programming language of choice. Heck, you could even just write a stored proc in the master DB and give them permission to execute that.